# I/O using system calls

Tags: c, operating-system

I have a file bisht.txt and pranav.txt. I want to copy content from bisht.txt to pranav.txt.
The read system call is working properly because I printed str right after it, which printed the exact content of the file but when I check the contents of destination file that is pranav.txt, some Chinese language is written into it but the no. of characters are the same as the no. of bytes mentioned in the write system call. Please help!

```
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
//FILE Descriptor rdes and wdes

/*Open file pranav.txt in write-only mode,
O_CREAT creates file if it does not exist and open bisht.txt in read-only mode*/
int rdes = open("bisht.txt",O_RDONLY);   
int wdes = open("pranav.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

char str[10];
if(wdes!=-1 && rdes!=-1)
{
    //To read
    read(rdes,&str,10);
    //To write on file
    write(wdes,&str,10);
}
else
{
    //Print "error" on screen
    write(2,"File_Opening_Error",18);
}
close(wdes);
close(rdes);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 10 or less bytes in bisht.txt?

Comment: Yup, I have written "Bisht" in it just for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the return from the read to write the bytes. The `read` function returns the number of bytes actually read:

```
int cnt;
cnt=read(rdes,&str,sizeof(str));
if(cnt>0) { write(wdes,&str,cnt); }
```

And technically the write may return a short count so you should write in a loop until all the bytes were written, or `-1` which indicates an error. Though for a local storage device a short-write will probably never happen.